# Jquery Waypoints not detecting viewport

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I'm using jquery waypoints to add/remove classes. Right now, I'm loading documents into a wrapper div. Code goes like this:

```
$(function () {
         $('.content-section').load('about.html');
     });
```

However, when it loads the html document, all the classes are added to their corresponding elements, even if they're not in viewport. The only way to get it working properly is if I adjust the screen size and back, then it starts to detect elements on their viewport properly.

Anyone know why this is occurring?

EDIT: I should also mention that I tested my website without loading external html docs. For example, I dropped all the elements from the 'about.html' into the main wrapper div, which is in another html doc of course, and waypoints detected the viewport just fine.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how that'll work when I have to load different html docs. Waypoints detects viewport just fine when I don't have to load outside html docs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is set to run on dom ready with `$(function(){`.

If you only want this to run on window resize, then wrap your code with that event like so:

```
$(function(){

    $( window ).resize(function() {

        $('.content-section').load('about.html');

    });
```

});

You can read more about the jQuery resize event here: https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I'm sorry I think you misunderstood what I was saying. I'm not having any trouble with waypoints when I resize. I'm saying that during the initial loading of the html document, waypoints doesn't detect viewport properly. Once I resize the screen THEN it starts to work fine.